# jQuery .prop to add/remove class on radio button - not working

Tags: jquery, checkbox, radio-button

I need to add/remove a generic class (something like .is-checked) on a series of radio buttons and checkboxes. Here's the code I have:

```
$(function () {
  $('input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"]').each(function () {
    $(this).on('click', function () {
      $(this).parent().wrap('<div>').unwrap();  
        // works great for checkboxes, but not for radios
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
          $(this).addClass('is-checked');
        } else {
          $(this).removeClass('is-checked');
        }
    })
  })
})
```

This works perfectly on checkboxes, but on the class that gets added to radio buttons never gets removed. Thoughts? Ideas?

**EDIT**
I accidentally neglected to mention that this script will be conditionally loaded for IE8 since the ':checked' pseudo selector is not supported. The entire feature works perfectly fine in everything but IE8, so this is a crutch for that browser and the poor users stuck dealing with it. In the end, the 'is-checked' class will trigger the same CSS that the :checked selector does.

Comment: why are u using `$(this).on('click', function () {` in your `each` ? can u elaborate?

Comment: Your code seems to work for me. Both click events are firing and are setting the `is-checked` class. http://jsfiddle.net/xzNPh/

Comment: @WillemEllis could be a difference in jquery versions (think it was 1.6 that changed the behaviors of `attr` and `prop`)

Comment: Instead of using an `.is-checked` class, why not just use `:checked` in your css?

Comment: @hungerpain I'm not sure why this wouldn't require a click event. The whole idea is that the user will manually changes the state of the inputs at least once, if not many times.

Comment: @KevinB I edited my original question with the reason for not using `:checked`. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: @cmegown i meant u neednt do this using a loop. jQuery wil take of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now see what you're after. The problem is with this line:

```
$(this).removeClass('is-checked');
```

It's only removing `.is-checked` from the element that was clicked. This works for checkboxes, but since radios work differently, this isn't going to work. To solve this, do something like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"]').on('click', function () {
        $(this).parent().wrap('<div>').unwrap();
        $('input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"]').each(function () {
            $(this).is(':checked') ? $(this).addClass('is-checked') : $(this).removeClass('is-checked');
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xzNPh/4/

Answer (score 1):

Try to use native property:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"]').on('click', function () {
      $(this).parent().wrap('<div>').unwrap(); 
      if (this.checked) {
          $(this).addClass('is-checked');
      } else {
          $(this).removeClass('is-checked');
      }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var inputs = $('input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"]');
inputs.on('click', function () {
    $(this).parent().wrap('<div>').unwrap();  
    inputs.removeClass('is-checked');
    $(this).toggleClass('is-checked', $(this).prop('checked', true));
});
```

You haven't explain what's it for, so I won't venture a guess if you even need that code. Eg. if it's only styling then maybe css would do just fine here.

And a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3A98Q/)